# JPA, Postgresql: Is there any performance difference between oid and TEXT?

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I'm using JPA with a postgresql database and also using Hibernates hbm2ddl to generate the initial DB schema.

I have a Java String field in my entity object that will need to be large.  When I annotate it with @Lob hbm2ddl generates an oid db column, however I can also use @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT") to get a TEXT db column.

I've tried searching the internet but I can't find any comparison between the performance or other benefits of oid's vs TEXT columns.  Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: You should read [Large Object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html) in particular [Introduction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/lo-intro.html).  The `oid` is a pointer to an object stored elsewhere.

Comment: Large Objects are really cumbersome to handle and unless you need to store strings > 1G there is absolutely no need to use them. It's really frustrating that Hibernate still uses "large objects" for Lobs.